# Difference between Leitung and Geschäftsführung

Tags: synonym

Are these two words synonyms?

I've seen **Leitung** for a team-leading role (Projektleiterin), but is **Geschäftsführung** for executives only?

Any better examples ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Geschäftsführung** is a clearly defined business term - according to [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesch%C3%A4ftsf%C3%BChrung_%28Deutschland%29) it is:

> [..]ein Rechtsbegriff, mit dem entweder das Organ oder die Funktion
>   der Leitung einer Gesellschaft beschrieben wird.

(meaning that it's a function or person leading a company)

**Leitung** can mean something like *Firmenleitung*, which would be somewhat equal to Geschäftsführung, but is used for all types of leadership, e.g. *Teamleiter* (team leader), Abteilungsleiter (department leader).

Comment: `Geschäftsführung` need not be a `Leitung`. An example are private schools, where `Schulleitung=Head Mastership` and `Geschäftsführung`=`Executive bla` are split.

Answer (score 4):

No, they are definitely not synonyms.

`Leitung` means leading role. This refers to people in a lead regarding to certain subjects or other people. This doesn't imply any size or number of the led.

`Geschäftsführung` is an executive role. These people may decide upon every management aspect.

Comment: leitung means leadership... that's all. no more, no less.

Comment: @FranzEbner Maybe, but I'm not good enough in English to know all the details in the meaning of `leadership`.

Comment: What I meant is, that "Leitung" doesn't imply the rank of the leader. So a "Leiter" can be a teamlead as well as a leader of a division or multinational corporation, it's just not specified.

Comment: @FranzEbner That's what I wrote in my answer: team lead=lead regarding a certain subject, division lead=lead regarding people.

Comment: You stated, that "Leitung" and "Geschäftsführung" are no synonyms. That's because the lack of information about the "Leitung". But it still could be a "Geschäftsleitung", which would be a Synonym in this, specific, case. A "Leitung" is still no "team-leading" but a "leading" role.

Comment: @FranzEbner A team may contain only one member.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to throw in here, that `Leitung` is not only restricted to leadership.

With `Leitung` people also refer to lines, cords, pipes and similar.
This is of course not the meaning they'd get in your context, but that exists ;).

On a sidenote `Die Leitung` can also mean `the leading` (not role, but activity) as in:

> Die Leitung übernimmt Herr X. Er ist verantwortlich.
>   The leading will be done by Mr. X. He is responsible.

Comment: You could also mention "Anleitung", "Umleitung" and such. Finde ich hier nicht sonderlich hilfreich.

Comment: @Robert Problematisch ist nur, dass Anleitung und Umleitung anders geschrieben werden als dieses Teekesselchen. Auch war das nur als addendum gedacht, aber zu langfür einen Kommentar.